# Find and return polygons which path/route goes through in PostGIS

Tags: postgresql, postgis, qgis, pgrouting

Hi I am challenged with finding the polygons which a path, returned as a multilinestring, crosses or drives through. So if I have to travel from A to B then I have to count and return all the polygons that I visit, including the polygons A and B are contained in. How is this achievable in PostGIS?

So I have a map and route looking something like this: [MAP with approx route](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CkslY.png)

and the multilinestring that I get returned can be seen here

> {
>       "type": "MultiLineString",
>       "coordinates": [
>           [
>               [9.3555111, 57.1437626],
>               [9.354822, 57.1438372],
>               [9.3535543, 57.1440033]
>           ],
>           [
>               [9.3561095, 57.1437043],
>               [9.3555111, 57.1437626]
>           ],
>           [
>               [9.3572876, 57.1435895],
>               [9.3561095, 57.1437043]
>           ],
>           [
>               [9.3574905, 57.1435697],
>               [9.3572876, 57.1435895]
>           ],
>           [
>               [9.3578022, 57.1435618],
>               [9.3574905, 57.1435697]
>           ],
>           [
>               [9.3579576, 57.1435655],
>               [9.3578022, 57.1435618]
>           ],
>           [
>               [9.3571448, 57.1462326],
>               [9.3571254, 57.1461296],
>               [9.3571139, 57.1459493],
>               [9.3571267, 57.1457911],
>               [9.3571777, 57.1455926],
>               [9.3572617, 57.1453846],
>               [9.3576578, 57.1445901],
>               [9.3578012, 57.1442991],
>               [9.3579052, 57.1439939],
>               [9.3579244, 57.1439216],
>               [9.3579576, 57.1435655]
>           ],
>           [
>               [9.3572195, 57.1462287],
>               [9.3571448, 57.1462326]
>           ],
>           [
>               [9.3572195, 57.1462287],
>               [9.3572649, 57.146383],
>               [9.357327, 57.1465307],
>               [9.3574453, 57.1467449],
>               [9.3575921, 57.1469549],
>               [9.3577695, 57.1471422],
>               [9.3579757, 57.1473145],
>               [9.3584842, 57.1476965],
>               [9.3593117, 57.1483147]
>           ],
>           [
>               [9.3593117, 57.1483147],
>               [9.3594894, 57.1482729],
>               [9.3597109, 57.1482499],
>               [9.3599176, 57.148252],
>               [9.3600273, 57.148263]
>           ],
>           [
>               [9.3600273, 57.148263],
>               [9.3602192, 57.1482932],
>               [9.3608886, 57.1484771]
>           ],
>           [
>               [9.3608886, 57.1484771],
>               [9.3614141, 57.1485938],
>               [9.3619974, 57.1486991],
>               [9.3626358, 57.1487903],
>               [9.3631325, 57.1488405],
>               [9.3636579, 57.1488672],
>               [9.3647925, 57.1488727],
>               [9.366019, 57.1488006],
>               [9.366409, 57.1487376]
>           ],
>           [
>               [9.366409, 57.1487376],
>               [9.3669798, 57.1486454],
>               [9.3679406, 57.148418],
>               [9.3681876, 57.1483527]
>           ],
>           [
>               [9.3681876, 57.1483527],
>               [9.3683101, 57.1483157]
>           ],
>           [
>               [9.3683101, 57.1483157],
>               [9.3724174, 57.1470762],
>               [9.3774741, 57.1455547]
>           ],
>           [
>               [9.3774741, 57.1455547],
>               [9.3811383, 57.1444522],
>               [9.3858889, 57.1430227],
>               [9.3893335, 57.1419691],
>               [9.3926962, 57.1409709],
>               [9.3942157, 57.1405259]
>           ],
>           [
>               [9.3942157, 57.1405259],
>               [9.3943623, 57.1404829],
>               [9.394568, 57.1404381]
>           ],
>           [
>               [9.394568, 57.1404381],
>               [9.3958137, 57.1401667],
>               [9.3975206, 57.1398451],
>               [9.3989005, 57.1396787],
>               [9.4002496, 57.1395567],
>               [9.4014251, 57.1395012],
>               [9.4056873, 57.139296],
>               [9.4100677, 57.1390735]
>           ],
>           [
>               [9.4100677, 57.1390735],
>               [9.4107366, 57.1390742],
>               [9.4121471, 57.1390797],
>               [9.4130772, 57.1391241],
>               [9.4139562, 57.1391796],
>               [9.4151828, 57.1392905],
>               [9.4177483, 57.1396621],
>               [9.4222353, 57.1403331],
>               [9.4230122, 57.1404551],
>               [9.4239014, 57.1405716],
>               [9.4268349, 57.14086],
>               [9.4287227, 57.1410362]
>           ],
>           [
>               [9.4287227, 57.1410362],
>               [9.4295318, 57.1411117]
>           ],
>           [
>               [9.4295318, 57.1411117],
>               [9.4312913, 57.1412759],
>               [9.4334173, 57.1414589],
>               [9.4357477, 57.1417695],
>               [9.4410116, 57.1424737],
>               [9.444589, 57.1429507],
>               [9.4468172, 57.1432335],
>               [9.4487797, 57.1435052],
>               [9.4499035, 57.1436858],
>               [9.4511325, 57.1440427],
>               [9.4521711, 57.1444277],
>               [9.4532933, 57.1449746],
>               [9.4536954, 57.1452012]
>           ],
>           [
>               [9.4536954, 57.1452012],
>               [9.4539329, 57.1450673],
>               [9.4541521, 57.1450064]
>           ],
>           [
>               [9.4541521, 57.1450064],
>               [9.4571546, 57.1432029]
>           ],
>           [
>               [9.4571546, 57.1432029],
>               [9.4575749, 57.1429363]
>           ],
>           [
>               [9.4632247, 57.1440417],
>               [9.4575749, 57.1429363]
>           ],
>           [
>               [9.4677832, 57.1449625],
>               [9.4632247, 57.1440417]
>           ],
>           [
>               [9.4702609, 57.1449583],
>               [9.468828, 57.1449876],
>               [9.4682462, 57.1449956],
>               [9.4677832, 57.1449625]
>           ],
>           [
>               [9.4730542, 57.1449118],
>               [9.4702609, 57.1449583]
>           ],
>           [
>               [9.4736102, 57.1448992],
>               [9.4730542, 57.1449118]
>           ],
>           [
>               [9.476478, 57.1448101],
>               [9.4758299, 57.1448487],
>               [9.4736102, 57.1448992]
>           ],
>           [
>               [9.4776624, 57.1447481],
>               [9.4770398, 57.1447683],
>               [9.476478, 57.1448101]
>           ],
>           [
>               [9.4797556, 57.1450294],
>               [9.4784706, 57.1449687],
>               [9.4781911, 57.1449135],
>               [9.4779318, 57.1448253],
>               [9.4776624, 57.1447481]
>           ],
>           [
>               [9.482506, 57.1453423],
>               [9.4806997, 57.1451109],
>               [9.4797556, 57.1450294]
>           ],
>           [
>               [9.4856798, 57.1453847],
>               [9.4833677, 57.1453751],
>               [9.482506, 57.1453423]
>           ],
>           [
>               [9.4878125, 57.145319],
>               [9.4863807, 57.1453842],
>               [9.4856798, 57.1453847]
>           ],
>           [
>               [9.4886688, 57.1452634],
>               [9.4878125, 57.145319]
>           ],
>           [
>               [9.4896027, 57.1452074],
>               [9.4886688, 57.1452634]
>           ],
>           [
>               [9.4900872, 57.1451784],
>               [9.4896027, 57.1452074]
>           ],
>           [
>               [9.4915526, 57.1450695],
>               [9.4900872, 57.1451784]
>           ],
>           [
>               [9.5033371, 57.144857],
>               [9.4925869, 57.1449936],
>               [9.4915526, 57.1450695]
>           ],
>           [
>               [9.5062344, 57.1466448],
>               [9.5056962, 57.1464416],
>               [9.5051967, 57.14621],
>               [9.5033371, 57.144857]
>           ],
>           [
>               [9.5153133, 57.1490422],
>               [9.5152178, 57.1489798],
>               [9.5150239, 57.1488945],
>               [9.5143783, 57.1486929],
>               [9.5120804, 57.1480541],
>               [9.5080348, 57.1470259],
>               [9.5070276, 57.1468355],
>               [9.5062344, 57.1466448]
>           ],
>           [
>               [9.516164, 57.151073],
>               [9.5161224, 57.1510048],
>               [9.516166, 57.1507837],
>               [9.5161656, 57.1506361],
>               [9.5161163, 57.1504358],
>               [9.5156098, 57.1493643],
>               [9.515405, 57.1491178],
>               [9.5153133, 57.1490422]
>           ],
>           [
>               [9.517273, 57.1512057],
>               [9.5164759, 57.1511709],
>               [9.5162961, 57.1511398],
>               [9.516164, 57.151073]
>           ],
>           [
>               [9.5254761, 57.1521458],
>               [9.5251101, 57.1520388],
>               [9.5247146, 57.1519563],
>               [9.5235082, 57.1517346],
>               [9.5230687, 57.1516258],
>               [9.5221932, 57.1512634],
>               [9.5219455, 57.1511788],
>               [9.5216993, 57.1511442],
>               [9.5214123, 57.1511386],
>               [9.5189081, 57.1512418],
>               [9.5182031, 57.1512418],
>               [9.517273, 57.1512057]
>           ],
>           [
>               [9.526051, 57.152711],
>               [9.5259224, 57.1526441],
>               [9.5258034, 57.1525262],
>               [9.525622, 57.1522691],
>               [9.5254761, 57.1521458]
>           ],
>           [
>               [9.5302396, 57.1529888],
>               [9.5265538, 57.1528129],
>               [9.5263203, 57.1527829],
>               [9.526051, 57.152711]
>           ],
>           [
>               [9.5336269, 57.1533783],
>               [9.5332398, 57.1532048],
>               [9.5330259, 57.1531359],
>               [9.5328073, 57.1531114],
>               [9.5302396, 57.1529888]
>           ],
>           [
>               [9.5387981, 57.1554757],
>               [9.5384128, 57.155428],
>               [9.5380023, 57.1553493],
>               [9.5376739, 57.1552415],
>               [9.5373527, 57.1550966],
>               [9.537085, 57.1549439],
>               [9.5368319, 57.1548143],
>               [9.5336269, 57.1533783]
>           ],
>           [
>               [9.5414655, 57.1558512],
>               [9.5413173, 57.1557635],
>               [9.5411112, 57.1556573],
>               [9.540898, 57.1556003],
>               [9.5405117, 57.155565],
>               [9.5387981, 57.1554757]
>           ],
>           [
>               [9.5416406, 57.1571697],
>               [9.5414383, 57.1559276],
>               [9.5414655, 57.1558512]
>           ],
>           [
>               [9.541798, 57.1581042],
>               [9.5416406, 57.1571697]
>           ],
>           [
>               [9.5421883, 57.1604317],
>               [9.541798, 57.1581042]
>           ],
>           [
>               [9.5422647, 57.160858],
>               [9.5421883, 57.1604317]
>           ],
>           [
>               [9.5429259, 57.1646325],
>               [9.5422647, 57.160858]
>           ],
>           [
>               [9.5577988, 57.1658202],
>               [9.5482666, 57.1650468],
>               [9.5431324, 57.1646357],
>               [9.5429259, 57.1646325]
>           ],
>           [
>               [9.5654501, 57.1664078],
>               [9.5642455, 57.1663137],
>               [9.5577988, 57.1658202]
>           ],
>           [
>               [9.567757, 57.1665879],
>               [9.5654501, 57.1664078]
>           ],
>           [
>               [9.5709973, 57.1668223],
>               [9.5708411, 57.1668176],
>               [9.567757, 57.1665879]
>           ],
>           [
>               [9.5709973, 57.1668223],
>               [9.5712722, 57.1668408],
>               [9.575661, 57.1671735],
>               [9.5757638, 57.1671973]
>           ],
>           [
>               [9.5877421, 57.1689964],
>               [9.5857565, 57.1685859],
>               [9.5817132, 57.1676194],
>               [9.5813375, 57.1675939],
>               [9.5788932, 57.1674225],
>               [9.5766478, 57.1672516],
>               [9.5757638, 57.1671973]
>           ],
>           [
>               [9.586522, 57.1701951],
>               [9.5877421, 57.1689964]
>           ],
>           [
>               [9.5933471, 57.1712614],
>               [9.5929056, 57.171103],
>               [9.5925623, 57.1710033],
>               [9.5921332, 57.1710598],
>               [9.5917225, 57.1711296],
>               [9.5911586, 57.1711097],
>               [9.5906988, 57.1710631],
>               [9.586522, 57.1701951]
>           ],
>           [
>               [9.59778, 57.1755274],
>               [9.5974602, 57.1752393],
>               [9.5973578, 57.1750332],
>               [9.5970679, 57.174671],
>               [9.5969331, 57.1746112],
>               [9.5966756, 57.1745481],
>               [9.5962342, 57.1743653],
>               [9.5960565, 57.1742523],
>               [9.5956764, 57.1741393],
>               [9.5953331, 57.1739233],
>               [9.5951553, 57.1737505],
>               [9.5951423, 57.173544],
>               [9.5950793, 57.1733709],
>               [9.5949001, 57.1732655],
>               [9.5950039, 57.1731825],
>               [9.5949776, 57.1730893],
>               [9.5948795, 57.1729563],
>               [9.5946833, 57.1728732],
>               [9.5940625, 57.1728038],
>               [9.5936719, 57.1727337],
>               [9.5934466, 57.1726295],
>               [9.5933211, 57.1725441],
>               [9.5931893, 57.1724999],
>               [9.5929699, 57.1724455],
>               [9.5929249, 57.1723807],
>               [9.5929664, 57.1722459],
>               [9.5929023, 57.172217],
>               [9.5927704, 57.1721109],
>               [9.5926788, 57.1719604],
>               [9.5929145, 57.1717318],
>               [9.5929827, 57.1715872],
>               [9.5930979, 57.1714821],
>               [9.5931311, 57.1714206],
>               [9.5932017, 57.1713511],
>               [9.5933471, 57.1712614]
>           ],
>           [
>               [9.6047945, 57.1747181],
>               [9.6045993, 57.1746559],
>               [9.6044316, 57.1746341],
>               [9.6037672, 57.1746425],
>               [9.6035456, 57.1746646],
>               [9.6024995, 57.1749798],
>               [9.6021384, 57.175039],
>               [9.6003157, 57.1752783],
>               [9.6000176, 57.175294],
>               [9.5990388, 57.1754059],
>               [9.59873, 57.1754157],
>               [9.59778, 57.1755274]
>           ],
>           [
>               [9.6127373, 57.1772197],
>               [9.6098243, 57.1763209],
>               [9.6062355, 57.1751704],
>               [9.6059362, 57.1750485],
>               [9.6047945, 57.1747181]
>           ],
>           [
>               [9.6136709, 57.1775394],
>               [9.6127373, 57.1772197]
>           ],
>           [
>               [9.6137431, 57.1775623],
>               [9.6136709, 57.1775394]
>           ],
>           [
>               [9.6226472, 57.1800812],
>               [9.6191266, 57.1792676],
>               [9.6137431, 57.1775623]
>           ],
>           [
>               [9.6247259, 57.1805615],
>               [9.6226472, 57.1800812]
>           ],
>           [
>               [9.626882, 57.1810791],
>               [9.6247259, 57.1805615]
>           ],
>           [
>               [9.6287287, 57.1818221],
>               [9.6287134, 57.1817708],
>               [9.6286223, 57.1816803],
>               [9.6280713, 57.1814399],
>               [9.626882, 57.1810791]
>           ],
>           [
>               [9.6287287, 57.1818221],
>               [9.6288488, 57.1818093],
>               [9.6289428, 57.1818202],
>               [9.6290759, 57.1818612],
>               [9.6293552, 57.1819947],
>               [9.629604, 57.1821842],
>               [9.6296353, 57.1822356],
>               [9.6296214, 57.1823002]
>           ],
>           [
>               [9.6303236, 57.1825125],
>               [9.6296214, 57.1823002]
>           ],
>           [
>               [9.6307599, 57.1826438],
>               [9.6303236, 57.1825125]
>           ],
>           [
>               [9.6324711, 57.183159],
>               [9.6307599, 57.1826438]
>           ],
>           [
>               [9.6354295, 57.1840354],
>               [9.6350074, 57.1839225],
>               [9.6324711, 57.183159]
>           ],
>           [
>               [9.6362413, 57.184182],
>               [9.6358706, 57.1841322],
>               [9.6354295, 57.1840354]
>           ],
>           [
>               [9.6367365, 57.1842275],
>               [9.6364984, 57.1842114],
>               [9.6362413, 57.184182]
>           ],
>           [
>               [9.6378766, 57.1842574],
>               [9.6367365, 57.1842275]
>           ],
>           [
>               [9.6390149, 57.1842935],
>               [9.6378766, 57.1842574]
>           ],
>           [
>               [9.6451831, 57.1850131],
>               [9.6444469, 57.1847934],
>               [9.643728, 57.1846266],
>               [9.6428365, 57.1844879],
>               [9.6419594, 57.1844018],
>               [9.6409752, 57.1843545],
>               [9.6390149, 57.1842935]
>           ],
>           [
>               [9.6465635, 57.1855788],
>               [9.6459567, 57.1853061],
>               [9.6451831, 57.1850131]
>           ],
>           [
>               [9.6522672, 57.1882655],
>               [9.6465635, 57.1855788]
>           ],
>           [
>               [9.6544744, 57.1893016],
>               [9.6540537, 57.1891092],
>               [9.6522672, 57.1882655]
>           ],
>           [
>               [9.6562787, 57.1900128],
>               [9.6558348, 57.1898745],
>               [9.6552766, 57.189656],
>               [9.6544744, 57.1893016]
>           ],
>           [
>               [9.6567186, 57.1901368],
>               [9.6562787, 57.1900128]
>           ],
>           [
>               [9.6575416, 57.1903173],
>               [9.6571738, 57.1902454],
>               [9.6567186, 57.1901368]
>           ],
>           [
>               [9.6627065, 57.190584],
>               [9.660466, 57.1905533],
>               [9.6596238, 57.1905408],
>               [9.6587971, 57.1904843],
>               [9.6582137, 57.1904215],
>               [9.6575416, 57.1903173]
>           ],
>           [
>               [9.6642627, 57.190681],
>               [9.663499, 57.1906151],
>               [9.6627065, 57.190584]
>           ],
>           [
>               [9.6683386, 57.1914239],
>               [9.6652064, 57.1908326],
>               [9.6642627, 57.190681]
>           ],
>           [
>               [9.6692696, 57.1916115],
>               [9.6683386, 57.1914239]
>           ],
>           [
>               [9.6722869, 57.1919033],
>               [9.6717856, 57.1918944],
>               [9.671251, 57.1918641],
>               [9.6707397, 57.1918245],
>               [9.6701725, 57.1917563],
>               [9.6697747, 57.1916999],
>               [9.6692696, 57.1916115]
>           ],
>           [
>               [9.6721281, 57.1924274],
>               [9.6722869, 57.1919033]
>           ],
>           [
>               [9.6719929, 57.1929592],
>               [9.6721281, 57.1924274]
>           ],
>           [
>               [9.6719054, 57.1933035],
>               [9.6719929, 57.1929592]
>           ],
>           [
>               [9.6718815, 57.1934584],
>               [9.6718858, 57.1933804],
>               [9.6719054, 57.1933035]
>           ],
>           [
>               [9.6719676, 57.1941722],
>               [9.6718748, 57.1935809],
>               [9.6718815, 57.1934584]
>           ],
>           [
>               [9.6720584, 57.1948215],
>               [9.6719676, 57.1941722]
>           ],
>           [
>               [9.6720879, 57.1950329],
>               [9.6720584, 57.1948215]
>           ],
>           [
>               [9.672901, 57.1950078],
>               [9.6720879, 57.1950329]
>           ],
>           [
>               [9.672901, 57.1950078],
>               [9.6729386, 57.195217]
>           ],
>           [
>               [9.6729386, 57.195217],
>               [9.6729586, 57.1953285]
>           ],
>           [
>               [9.6729601, 57.195406],
>               [9.6729586, 57.1953285]
>           ],
>           [
>               [9.6730101, 57.1961026],
>               [9.6729816, 57.1955673],
>               [9.6729601, 57.195406]
>           ],
>           [
>               [9.6731242, 57.1960885],
>               [9.6730101, 57.1961026]
>           ],
>           [
>               [9.6732539, 57.1973861],
>               [9.6732154, 57.1973583],
>               [9.6731685, 57.1962711],
>               [9.6731242, 57.1960885]
>           ],
>           [
>               [9.6738644, 57.1973537],
>               [9.6732923, 57.1974023],
>               [9.6732539, 57.1973861]
>           ]
>       ]
>   }

In my map table I only have the geom data as polygons. So I am thinking that it should be possible to check a set og coordinates if there are contained in a geom->polygon but how? Cannot seem to figure out how to use the ST functions and which one exactly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use st_intersects: you are looking for the polygons that intersects your route (multi)linestring.

Your query will be something like this

```
select polygons.id from polygons
where st_intersects(polygons.geometry, ST_GeomFromGeoJSON('GEOJSON HERE'))
```